# How i can tell jsonschem to need one/more of patternProperties?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I developed this schema

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["users"],
    "properties": {
        "users":{
            "type":"object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "patternProperties": {
                "^APP-[A-Z_-]+$": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
                },
                "^[A-Za-z0-9\\._%\\+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "user":{
            "type":"object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "full_name": {"type": "string", "pattern": "^[^\\s]+(\\s+[^\\s]+)*$"},
                "email": {"type": "string", "format": "email"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to meet the following document

```json
{
    "users": {
        "APP-TEST": {
            "full_name": "test",
            "email": "test@local.com"
        },
        "user1@local.com": {
            "full_name": "test",
            "email": "test@local.com"
        },
        "user2@local.com": {
            "full_name": "test",
            "email": "test@local.com"
        }
    }
}
```

But I am stuck at how can validate the JSON document at example to say i want one of "APP-" key and many of "email-pattern-users" keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "I need at least one property matching this pattern" by using the `not` keyword and the `false` schema:

```
{
  "not": { "patternProperties": { "^APP-[A-Z_-]+$": false } }
}
```

That is: "if there is a matching pattern property, then true, otherwise false"

However, I do not see a way of distinguishing between requiring exactly one matching property and at least two matching properties.

Comment: That `if` schema will always be true and the `else` will never apply. You could change the `true` to `false` and put the whole thing in a `not` to make it work.

Comment: Actually, you could simplify it even further. The `if`/`else` isn't necessary. `{ "not": { "patternProperties": { "^APP-[A-Z_-]+$": false } } }`.